# How do I style the datetime input using simple form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, slim-lang

I'm using simple form with slim to create the service form for my application.

I have something like this code:

```
= f.input :start_at, input_html: { 'style' => 'width: 18%; display: inline' }
```

But I want something customized. How do I style with css each select input (day, month, year, hour, minutes) in simple form datetime input.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'form-control input-sm', value: c.object.start_at.strftime("%e-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I want to put a css class in each select input to style it.

Comment: i usually add this in the simple form = simple_nested_form_for @customer, html:{class: 'customer_details_form form'}, remote: true, method: :put, defaults: {input_html: {class:'form-control input-sm', require: true}} do |f|

Comment: I update for this code = f.input_field :start_at, class: 'form-control input-sm', value: '#{f.object.start_at.strftime("%e-%m-%Y")}'

But I didn't get what I really want. In this way I got all the select inputs with the same css classes, but I can't put a specific css class for each one.. like: class: 'form-control' for only day select input, but not for the rest